# Date Insertion Issue in Oracle Database and Codeigniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I am having a problem in updating oracle db table with date column . I have tried many solutions but still not working. **I can not insert the date into the database** using codeigniter active record or normal query..  the column type is Timestamp. here are some solutions I have tried. could u help please.. thank you

```
 $this->db->set('AC_START',"TO_DATE('2014-03-4 2:30','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')");
 $this->db->set('AC_END',"TO_DATE('2014-05-5 2:34' ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')");
 $this->db->insert('ACTIVITES');
```

here is error message that I always get

Error Number:

```
INSERT INTO "LI_PPPA"."ACTIVITES" ("AC_START", "AC_END") VALUES ('TO_DATE('2014-03-4 2:30','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')', 'TO_DATE('2014-05-5 2:34' ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')')
```

**Filename:**  Directory\program\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure CI doens't escape the values you are passing to the oracle database, because `to_date` is an oracle function.

Try the following:

```
 $this->db->set('AC_START',"TO_DATE('2014-03-4 2:30','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')",FALSE);
 $this->db->set('AC_END',"TO_DATE('2014-05-5 2:34' ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')",FALSE);
 $this->db->insert('ACTIVITES');code here
```

With that last parameter you are telling CodeIgniter to NOT escape this value.

Answer (score 0):

Sonaryr's answer threw an Oracle error for me: [ORA-01810](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01810.php)

**Oracle SQL Developer Statement Output:**

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01810: format code appears twice
01810. 00000 -  "format code appears twice"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

**To Fix Change MM to MI:**

```
$this->db->set('AC_START',"TO_DATE('2015-09-02 16:35' ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')",FALSE);
```

Answer (score -1):

Write Normal Query To Perform Action Against The TO_DATE(); Codegniter Does not have any library functions for to_date() for oracle.